# what is fileid specification?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm going to retrieve a file from Google Drive and save it to my local directory.
Then I want to name the file like titlename_fileid.
In this case, I assume the separator is "_". To decide which character should be the separator, please tell me which character is not used for fileid.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen underscores '_' and dashes '-' are used.

Comment: I see. At least I won't use underscores '_'. Maybe I should change my idea... Thanks.

Comment: put the file ID as #[your fileid]. Not sure your OS will like that... but it is a good seperator.